# Chrome dev tools opens an old file when I try to debug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a javascript file, but whenever I use the Chrome Devtools, a random old JS file opens instead. I haven't been able to move on with my project because of this. Does anybody know why it won't read the current file? You can see down on the gif that I am using index.js but every time I debug it opens a random file and reads that instead.

[GIF OF THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBGQs.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project uses webpack. Make sure you keep it running. The VScode extension LiveServer will take changes but will only work with the JS file you had the last time you ran it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with caching. Try using a silent browser and disabling caching

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIxEL.png)

Comment: my caching is disabled. I also tried hard reset. I have no idea why it keeps doing that.

Comment: Well, it's a strange thing, and it happens occasionally, to make sure that the `JS` requested is what you think it is, maybe consider adding  `version number` or  `timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

The browser caches your old JS file. So what you can do on Chrome is perform a hard refresh with CTRL + Shift + R while the dev tool is open.

Comment: I already did that and it still doesn't work.